Changing time format on RCUTILS_CONSOLE_OUTPUT_FORMAT
In ROS 1, you could set modify the representation of utc time to a more readable format with something like
export ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT="[${severity}] [${walltime:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}] [${node}]; ${message}"

In ROS 2 you can't seem to do that. I tried:
export RCUTILS_CONSOLE_OUTPUT_FORMAT="{time:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}[{severity}] [{name}] ({function_name}() at {file_name}:{line_number}); {message}"

which will just render as time:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S as opposed to replacing it with the readable actual time.
Is there way to format the time of logs in ROS 2 on the fly?

A full time spec, as you wrote in your example, is not possible. However, since ROS 2 Jazzy, there is an extra format specifier date_time_with_ms which gives similar output:
$ export RCUTILS_CONSOLE_OUTPUT_FORMAT="[{severity} {date_time_with_ms}] [{name}]: {message}"
$ ros2 run examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher publisher_member_function
[INFO 2024-06-11 09:13:56.318] [minimal_publisher]: Publishing: 'Hello, world! 0'
[INFO 2024-06-11 09:13:56.818] [minimal_publisher]: Publishing: 'Hello, world! 1'
[INFO 2024-06-11 09:13:57.318] [minimal_publisher]: Publishing: 'Hello, world! 2'

The other specifiers are time and time_as_nanoseconds, see here.
